# Google Docs: references to a field

Tags: google-docs

A report typed in Google docs refers to the same incident date.   Is it possible to  define the first instance of this date as the "incidentDate" field and insert a reference (copy of the date) throughout the document as needed, so as to when the field is changed in the first instance, the references are changed.

What is the terminology for this idea in G-docs and how is this performed?

Answer (score 1):

Google Docs hasn't the "fields" feature but you could add it by using Google Apps Script or an add-on. You can find add-ons by clicking in the **Add-ons** menu in the Google Docs toolbar then on **Get add-ons**.

With Google Apps Script you might store the "incident date" somewhere. One option is to use the document properties by using the Properties Service more specifically the [getDocumentProperties()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getDocumentProperties()) method. This could be managed directly from the script editor, or you might create a custom menu.

Related

- [Inserting replaceable text for later?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/123127/88163)

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/documents
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties